# Get \p{L}+ to match string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been banging my head against the wall for an hour or so now trying everything I can think of to get \p{L}+ to match a string in javascript. The below returns false every time and I don't know why. It works in my local regex tester and works on regex101.com but fails in situ.

```
var reg = /\d\d\ \p{L}+\ \d\d\d\d/;
return (reg.test('30 october 2014'));
```

I've googled a ton of things about this but all to no avail.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

The reason I've gone down this route as opposed to [a-zA-Z] is because I will need to match accented latin as well.

Comment: In [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bO9qF4/1), you didn't change the flavour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't currently support Unicode regular expression categories. I suggest using [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) and its [Unicode addon](http://xregexp.com/plugins/).

Comment: Ah, I had a feeling it would be something like this. I have tried XRegExp but it wouldn't play for me

Comment: @Drew: I've used XRegExp quite a bit and it's always worked well for me. Perhaps you didn't use the correct syntax?

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me!