# How to convert PHP Regex to jQuery Regex

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I have this PHP regex:

```
/^[\p{L}\p{M}]+[\p{L}\p{M}\-\s]*$/u
```

and I want to convert it to jQuery. I tried multiple solutions that I found online, but nothing really worked. I tried using

```
new RegExp("/^[\p{L}\p{M}]+[\p{L}\p{M}\-\s]*$/u");
```

but that didn't help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP Regex syntax, but it shouldn't be hard to translate if you use https://regexr.com/

Answer (score -1):

This is because `\p{L}` and `\p{M}` don't exist in the JavaScript RegEx engine. This answer provides solutions for matching Unicode categories: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26659285/1920035